# Python writer.writerow(data) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, xml, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why do I get the error `valueerror:I/O operation on closed file`?

```
import urllib2
import csv


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.tendersinfo.com/rss/index.php?sector_name=0202&notice_type=1,2,3,7,10,11,16,8"

with open('tender.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['TITLE', 'LINK', 'DESCRIPTION']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    resource = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    url = resource.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
    soup.prettify()

    title = soup.find_all('title')
    link = soup.find_all('link')
    description = soup.find_all('description')

listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(2, 16)
for i in listIterator:
    data = [[title[i].get_text('')]]
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Here is error:

> C:\Python27\python.exe D:/PycharmProjects/tenderinfo/tendorinfo.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/PycharmProjects/tenderinfo/tendorinfo.py", line 32, in 
>       writer.writerow(data) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

i need to scrap that link and put that into a csv file. please help  with that.

Comment: In python indentation is NOT optional...

Comment: why are you creating a DictWriter and a writer instead of just creating a writer and writing the fieldnames as a row?

Answer (score 3):

This is an indentation problem. Move the last block to under the `with` body:

```
with open('tender.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    # ...

    # the following block should also be under "with" since it uses "writer"
    # which writes to csvfile that needs to be opened for writing at this moment
    listIterator = []
    listIterator[:] = range(2, 16)
    for i in listIterator:
        data = [[title[i].get_text('')]]
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: i am new to python programming, so having problems with indentation, can you please put the correct formatted line of code here, so that i can parse XML to a csv using beautifulsoup